# What is wrong with this way to reverse a linked list recursively?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list using recursion, but somehow it's not working. I know something I am doing is obviously wrong, but I would really appreciate any advice.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node * next;
};

typedef Node* nodePtr;

void reverseList(nodePtr &list) {
    nodePtr temp = list;
    if (temp->next == nullptr) {
        list = temp;
        return;
    }
    else {
        reverseList(temp->next);
        nodePtr temp2 = temp->next;
        temp2->next = temp;
        temp->next = nullptr;
    }
}

void insertEnd(nodePtr &list, int data) {
    nodePtr temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    if (list == nullptr) {
        list = temp;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr temp2 = list;
        while(temp2->next != nullptr) {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp;
    }
}

void printList(nodePtr list) {
    nodePtr temp = list;
    cout << "The list is: " << endl;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    nodePtr head = new Node;
    head = nullptr;
    insertEnd(head, 1);
    insertEnd(head, 2);
    insertEnd(head, 3);
    insertEnd(head, 4);
    insertEnd(head, 5);
    insertEnd(head, 6);
    printList(head);
    reverseList(head);
    printList(head);
}
```

The `insertEnd()` and `printList()` functions work correctly, as every time I run it, it prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

However, when I invoke the `reverseList()` function and try to print that, it only prints:

```
1
```

Comment: Well, the *first* thing you're doing wrong is using recursion here :-) Recursion is ideal if the problem space reduces quickly for each level, like a binary search being able to throw away half the problem space each time. Using recursion for list reversal is like adding `a=10` and `b=30` by continuously adding `1` to `a` and subtracting `1` from `b`, until `b` reaches `0`.

Comment: Good example code. Short and sweet, reproduces the problem easily and passes the low-hanging fruit test: https://godbolt.org/z/jbdnsb46P

Comment: Have you stepped through the `reverseList` function with a debugger yet? If not, you should.

Comment: @paxdiablo Hello, thanks for your answer, I know that recursions is not the best for inverting a Linked List, I can do it without an issue in an iterative way, but I know it's possible and wanted to practice how to do it anyway.

Comment: Note: `if (temp->next == nullptr)` doesn't check to make sure `temp` itself isn't null. That'll bite you sooner or later.

Comment: You never pass along the original `head` to the recursive calls; your top level pointer never gets reassigned. The check for nullptr doesn't make any sense. This leaks memory everywhere, including your main function where you `new Node` only to leak it on the next line.

Comment: @Luis, no problems. If it's for educational purposes, you can do all sorts of things you probably shouldn't in production code :-)

Comment: When you recurse to the last node in the list the code does `nodePtr temp = list;`, then finds next is null, then `list = temp;`, so we're pretty much right back where we started. Might as well just `return`.

Comment: The fatal flaw in `reverseList` can be easily understood by considering some very simple, elementary facts. It's obvious that `reverseList` starts things off by popping off the head node. But then, if you stop for a second and ponder what facts remain in play, you quickly realize that the rest of the logic needs to do two things: 1) return the reversed list (constructed from the remaining original list, after popping off the header), and 2) know the last node in the reversed list, for attaching the former head node. All that `reverseList` has to work with, though, is its lone parameter. Fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your else clause in the body of `reverseList` is just not doing the right thing. You pop the head, recursively reverse the list with the head removed, and then need to add the old head *to the tail* of the result of the recursive call.

Your code never deals with the fact that when you reverse part of the list you need the tail of what you reversed -- there is no getting around that. So you could either find that tail with a function that traverses a list and returns the last element, or you could return it in some way from your recursive call.

Below I do the latter, by taking an optional pointer to pointer that will fill the tail if the argument is not null.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

typedef Node* nodePtr;

void printList(nodePtr list) {
    nodePtr temp = list;
    cout << "The list is: " << endl;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void reverseList(nodePtr& list, nodePtr* tail = nullptr) {
    if (list->next == nullptr) {
        if (tail) {
            *tail = list;
        }
    } else {
        auto reversed = list->next;
        nodePtr tail_of_reversed = nullptr;
        reverseList(reversed, &tail_of_reversed);

        auto old_head = list;
        old_head->next = nullptr;
        tail_of_reversed->next = old_head;

        if (tail) {
            *tail = old_head;
        }
        list = reversed;
    }
}

void insertEnd(nodePtr& list, int data) {
    nodePtr temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    if (list == nullptr) {
        list = temp;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr temp2 = list;
        while (temp2->next != nullptr) {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp;
    }
}


int main() {
    nodePtr head = new Node;
    head = nullptr;
    insertEnd(head, 1);
    insertEnd(head, 2);
    insertEnd(head, 3);
    insertEnd(head, 4);
    insertEnd(head, 5);
    insertEnd(head, 6);
    printList(head);
    reverseList(head);
    printList(head);
}
```